# How to fetch data from Postgres db behind firewall for power bi report

Tags: postgresql, azure, powerbi, firewall, data-collection

I am having my data on Postgres DB on Azure behind the firewall. Because of firewall it is not possible to import data in Power bi. I want to publish the report on https://app.powerbi.com/. Any suggestion how this can be done?

Comment: Ask the owner of the database, he/she can tell you how you can get access to the data.

Comment: @FrankHeikens we are the owner of the database but as we are having firewall around the db that direct connection is not possible

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some major steps when importing the data into Power BI from Azure Database for PostgreSQL.

1. Install the ODBC driver
2. You have to add a rule to the firewall (inbound rule).

Refer https://niftit.com/connecting-power-bi-to-postgresql/ for more detailed explanation.

Comment: Is there any other way to connect to the database, other than adding an exception in the firewall as we want to host the power bi reports on private IPs

Comment: try this https://niftit.com/connecting-power-bi-to-postgresql/